# Calculate playback seconds in accelerated file

Tags: c#

I have an original file. Then, I've accelerated it in X%. I need to calculate seconds in accelerated file. For example 5 second in original file = x second in accelerated file. This is my code:

```
 private static TimeSpan GetSpeedUpTime(double seconds)
        {
            var time = new TimeSpan(0, 0, (int)Math.Floor(seconds));
            int increaseSpeedValue;
            int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IncreaseSpeedValue"], out increaseSpeedValue);
            return new TimeSpan(0, 0, (int)Math.Floor(seconds * increaseSpeedValue / 100));
        }
```

I can't understand what am I doing wrong? I know that task is very simple... but can't resolve it during an hour...

Comment: Is seconds the original time  -  and "IncreaseSpeedValue" the % by which you need to increase?  It's not clear which variable means what ...

Comment: What is *wrong* with this approach? What is it not doing properly? What is the expected output for an input of `5`? You stated `For example 5 second in original file = x second in accelerated file`, but fail to specify the exact relationship or what that specific example would result in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `increaseSpeedValue / 100` will be handled as integer division. [See remarks section here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx). This sets your TimeSpan to wrong.

The solution would be to cast to `(double)` or simply write `100.0`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was so easy... Thanks for your time. How I can miss it((